# Can't control log4j when running all maven tests

Tags: java, maven-3

In `src/test/resources/log4j.properties` I've configured log4j to not log anything.

When I run a single test, i.e. `mvn clean test -Dtest=MyTestClass`, this log4j properties is heeded. However, when I run all the tests, i.e. `mvn clean test`, this logging conf is ignored. How can this be?!!

I think I'm going crazy but hope there's a logical explanation :-)

Any help is highly appreciated.

```
$  mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.3.9
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_60, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-x64/jre
Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.6.0-1-amd64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

The sure fire version is 2.19.1:

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) @ common-util ---
```

The `src/test/resources/log4j.properties`:

```
log4j.rootLogger=OFF
```

POM fragments related to resources:

```
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
      <configuration>
        <encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Could you show the part of `pom.xml` that configures `resources`, please

Comment: I added the config of `maven-resources-plugin`, is that the one you meant? There's no interesting build plugins running in the `process-resources` phase (only one that generates JRebel XML files).

Comment: Is there something like `<build>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>${test.resource.directory}</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
...
</biuld>`

Comment: No, there's no such block. Also, I know that the location of `log4j.properties` works as it's heeded when I just run one unit test.

Comment: Why don't you try to specify the location of test resources in `pom.xml`?

Answer (score 2):

One of the 52 test classes under `src/test/java` had the following lines in its `@Before` method:

```
   import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;

   @Before
   public void setUp() {
     BasicConfigurator.resetConfiguration();
     BasicConfigurator.configure();
   }
```

For some reason, what must be a bug as far as I can tell, these calls to log4j affects all other junit classes too. Removing these lines made `mvn test` got the same logging behaviour as running `mvn test -Dtest=MyTestClass`, i.e. what was defined in `src/test/resources/log4j.properties`.